# openWRT Makefile for python backports-abc

Tags: openwrt

I'm attempting to build the backports-abc python module in to my OpenWRT build, and need a bit of help on the build/extraction process.

My issue seems to be that the downloaded backports-abc tar file extracts the content to backports_abc-0.5 due to the underlying tar file structure, but the build process is looking for the setup.py etc under backports-abc-0.5 (see below). I can manually copy the files over and rebuild, and that works fine, but that's not ideal. Also, though it builds OK, when I load the image to the device, the backports module is missing.

```
/home/ubuntu/build2/openwrt/staging_dir/host/bin/python2: can't open file './setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
Makefile:59: recipe for target '/home/ubuntu/build2/openwrt/build_dir/target-mipsel_24kec+dsp_uClibc-0.9.33.2/backports-abc-0.5//.built' failed
make[3]: *** [/home/ubuntu/build2/openwrt/build_dir/target-mipsel_24kec+dsp_uClibc-0.9.33.2/backports-abc-0.5//.built] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/build2/openwrt/feeds/linkit/python-backports-abc
```

'

The openWRT documentation around Makefiles is a bit vague, and so is my understanding of the process.

How do I get the tar file extracted to the right folder, or where in the Makefile process should I just copy the files to a correct folder?

Here's my Makefile.

```
include $(TOPDIR)/rules.mk

PKG_NAME:=backports_abc
PKG_VERSION:=0.5
PKG_RELEASE:=1
PKG_SOURCE:=backports_abc-0.5.tar.gz
PKG_SOURCE_URL:=https://pypi.python.org/packages/68/3c/1317a9113c377d1e33711ca8de1e80afbaf4a3c950dd0edfaf61f9bfe6d8/
PKG_MD5SUM:=7d1936ec183a3586290adf60f6f96764
PKG_BUILD_DIR:=$(BUILD_DIR)/$(PKG_NAME)-$(PKG_VERSION)/

#PKG_BUILD_DEPENDS:=python-setuptools

include $(INCLUDE_DIR)/package.mk
$(call include_mk, python-package.mk)

define Package/backports_abc
        SECTION:=lang-python
        CATEGORY:=Languages
        SUBMENU:=Python
        TITLE:=backports_abc
        URL:=https://pypi.python.org/pypi/backports_abc/0.5
        DEPENDS:=+python
endef

define Package/backports_abc/description
        A backport of recent additions to the 'collections.abc' module.
endef

define Build/Compile
        $(call Build/Compile/PyMod,., \
                install --prefix="/usr" --root="$(PKG_INSTALL_DIR)" \
        )
endef

define Build/InstallDev
        $(INSTALL_DIR) $(STAGING_DIR)$(PYTHON_PKG_DIR)
        $(CP) \
                $(PKG_INSTALL_DIR)$(PYTHON_PKG_DIR)/* \
                $(STAGING_DIR)$(PYTHON_PKG_DIR)/
        [ ! -e $(PKG_INSTALL_DIR)/usr/include ] || $(CP) \
                $(PKG_INSTALL_DIR)/usr/include/* \
                $(STAGING_DIR)/usr/include/
endef

define Package/backportsabc/install
        $(INSTALL_DIR) $(1)$(PYTHON_PKG_DIR)/
        $(CP) \
                $(PKG_INSTALL_DIR)$(PYTHON_PKG_DIR)/* \
                $(1)$(PYTHON_PKG_DIR)/
endef

$(eval $(call BuildPackage,backports_abc))
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy your Makefile somewhere in packages directory, and to overcome the issue remove PKG_BUILD_DIR variable from your Makefile.

Comment: Thanks. I've already resolved it (below) but your solution sounds like it may also work.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by fixing up some underscores and hyphens... ie: backports_abc and backports-abc
Basically..
This... `PKG_BUILD_DIR:=$(BUILD_DIR)/$(PKG_NAME)-$(PKG_VERSION)/`
meant that it was looking for the files based on the `PKG_NAME` variable.

```
include $(TOPDIR)/rules.mk

PKG_NAME:=backports_abc
PKG_VERSION:=0.5
PKG_RELEASE:=1
PKG_SOURCE:=backports_abc-0.5.tar.gz
PKG_SOURCE_URL:=https://pypi.python.org/packages/68/3c/1317a9113c377d1e33711ca8de1e80afbaf4a3c950dd0edfaf61f9bfe6d8/
PKG_MD5SUM:=7d1936ec183a3586290adf60f6f96764
PKG_BUILD_DIR:=$(BUILD_DIR)/$(PKG_NAME)-$(PKG_VERSION)/

#PKG_BUILD_DEPENDS:=python-setuptools 

include $(INCLUDE_DIR)/package.mk
$(call include_mk, python-package.mk)

define Package/backports-abc
    SECTION:=lang-python
    CATEGORY:=Languages
    SUBMENU:=Python
    TITLE:=backports-abc
    URL:=https://pypi.python.org/pypi/backports_abc/0.5
    DEPENDS:=+python
endef

define Package/backports-abc/description
    A backport of recent additions to the 'collections.abc' module.
endef

define Build/Compile
    $(call Build/Compile/PyMod,., \
        install --prefix="/usr" --root="$(PKG_INSTALL_DIR)" \
    )
endef

define Build/InstallDev
    $(INSTALL_DIR) $(STAGING_DIR)$(PYTHON_PKG_DIR)
    $(CP) \
        $(PKG_INSTALL_DIR)$(PYTHON_PKG_DIR)/* \
        $(STAGING_DIR)$(PYTHON_PKG_DIR)/
    [ ! -e $(PKG_INSTALL_DIR)/usr/include ] || $(CP) \
        $(PKG_INSTALL_DIR)/usr/include/* \
        $(STAGING_DIR)/usr/include/
endef

define Package/backports-abc/install
    $(INSTALL_DIR) $(1)$(PYTHON_PKG_DIR)/
    $(CP) \
        $(PKG_INSTALL_DIR)$(PYTHON_PKG_DIR)/* \
        $(1)$(PYTHON_PKG_DIR)/
endef

$(eval $(call BuildPackage,backports-abc))
```